# Wordpress conditionally load a minified script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a script that I only want to load up when someone is on a [particular page](https://debora.com.au/legal)

I load my scripts like this **Functions.php**:

```
function my_assets() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'footerlinks', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/footerlinks.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'gallery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/gallery.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'about', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/about.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'legal', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/legal.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );


if ( !is_page( 490 ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script('about');
}
if ( !is_page( 29804 ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script('legal');
}
if ( !is_page( 24574 ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script('gallery');
}

}

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets' );
```

This code works, but I'm also minifying and concatenating the scripts. When I do this part, the script doesn't become work, but it's still loaded up in the page without any errors.

Here is the script **legal.js**:

```
<!-- Script for making legal blurbs clickable to display one at a time -->
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".legaltab").hide();
    console.log("legal script running");
    var tprivacy = document.createAttribute("target");
    var ttc = document.createAttribute("target");
    var tdisclaimer = document.createAttribute("target");

    var bprivacy = document.getElementById("bprivacy");
    tprivacy.value = "sprivacy";
    bprivacy.setAttributeNode(tprivacy);

    var btc = document.getElementById("btc");
    ttc.value = "stc";
    btc.setAttributeNode(ttc);

    var bdisclaimer = document.getElementById("bdisclaimer");
    tdisclaimer.value = "sdisclaimer";
    bdisclaimer.setAttributeNode(tdisclaimer);


    jQuery(".legalblurb").click(function(){
    console.log("inside link button function");
        jQuery(".legaltab").hide();
        jQuery("#"+ jQuery(this).attr("target") ).show();
    }); 
});
```

Am I loading them up incorrectly? Some of the other questions discuss gulp or grunt, but I'm not sure if they are the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in your JS. For example in `legal.js` you have:

```
<!-- Script for making legal blurbs clickable to display one at a time -->
```

The correct way to add comments in Javascript is

```
// Script for making legal blurbs clickable to display one at a time
```

or

```
/* Script for making legal blurbs clickable to display one at a time */
```

I had a look at the compiled JS you have on the site and saw another bad commenting in the JS:

```
<!--Script for footer links that take you everywhere else-->
```

I would recommend you to use JavaScript [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and test your code using [JSHint](http://jshint.com/). That would drastically reduce minification errors.

A cleaned up version of `legal.js` would be:

```
/*globals jQuery*/
/* Script for making legal blurbs clickable to display one at a time */
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   'use strict';
    $(".legaltab").hide();
    console.log("legal script running");
    var tprivacy = document.createAttribute("target");
    var ttc = document.createAttribute("target");
    var tdisclaimer = document.createAttribute("target");

    var bprivacy = document.getElementById("bprivacy");
    tprivacy.value = "sprivacy";
    bprivacy.setAttributeNode(tprivacy);

    var btc = document.getElementById("btc");
    ttc.value = "stc";
    btc.setAttributeNode(ttc);

    var bdisclaimer = document.getElementById("bdisclaimer");
    tdisclaimer.value = "sdisclaimer";
    bdisclaimer.setAttributeNode(tdisclaimer);


    $(".legalblurb").click(function(){
    console.log("inside link button function");
        $(".legaltab").hide();
        $("#"+ $(this).attr("target") ).show();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you RRikesh, I've copied and pasted your code and removed the bad commenting from both files. The scripts still do not load up when minified though

Comment: Did you go through the other files? There are two ( [this](https://debora.com.au/wp-content/cache/min/1/427d9756ddc254553db322841962a580.js) and [this](https://debora.com.au/wp-content/cache/min/1/4ae3bd474ba1314ce91450c6e998be65.js) ) minified JavaScript files being loaded and they still exhibit lots of warnings when I paste them in [JS Hint](https://debora.com.au/wp-content/cache/min/1/4ae3bd474ba1314ce91450c6e998be65.js).

Comment: thank you so much, I was minifying all scripts into one file and that was causing the issue

Comment: Normally they _should_ be minified and concatenated into one file. But your code should be clean so that they don't break when they are minified.

Comment: Could you please point me in the right direction on how I could work on getting all the scripts to play nice in the same file? I remember in C++ I could only have 1 "main()" function, but Js is brand new to me. I guess I could start off with one script, test in jsHint, put another in the same file and test again and repeat till all scripts are working well.

Comment: check your `footerlinks.js`, `gallery.js`, `about.js`, and `legal.js`.

Comment: try minifying each file separately and loading them.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange for you, why don't you do:

```
wp_register_script( 'gallery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/gallery.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

if ( is_page( 24574 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('gallery');
}
```

The minify tool works based on the wp_enqueue_script function

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on how to conditionally load my scripts correctly. It still doesn't work when it is minified though

Answer (score 0):

First check that whether you are using any caching plugin or not. If you are using any plugins like that then please disable it. Clear your browser cache. After that make your code like this

```
wp_register_script( 'gallery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/gallery.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

if ( is_page( 'gallery' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('gallery');
}
```

It should work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have implemented your suggestion for loading the scripts, and checked incognito mode with chrome. Still will not load when the files are minified.